# How to fix image upload issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google cloud storage for hosting my website, i have code to upload the cover image like Facebook once user select the image it will upload to the server and same time it will fetch the image.

i gave full access to only that cover image folder, if i gave like that any problem will come like hacking. Please give me an advice my ways good or not?

```
if (!is_dir($directoryName)) {
                $oldmask = umask(0);
                mkdir($directoryName, 0777);
                umask($oldmask);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's even **possible** to use such method in the 1st place, since Cloud Storage doesn't actually have directories, file objects just ***appear*** to be residing in directories due to the `'/'` characters in their names, but they really are in the single flat namespace corresponding to the entire bucket. From [Object name considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations):

> Object names reside in a flat namespace within a bucket, which means
>   that different buckets can have objects with the same name. It also
>   means that objects do not reside within subdirectories in a bucket.
>   For example, you can name an object `/europe/france/paris.jpg` to make
>   it *appear* that `paris.jpg` resides in the subdirectory
>   `/europe/france`, but to Cloud Storage, the object simply exists in
>   the bucket and has the name `/europe/france/paris.jpg`.

The proper ways to implement access control in Cloud Storage are described in [Access Control Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/).

To me the most appealing one for uploading the cover photo appears to be using [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which allows access restricted to just a single file/object and only for a limited time, thus preventing upload of multiple files (which appears to be your concern) as well as overwriting the uploaded image after that limited time expires:

> This page provides an overview of Signed URLs, which is a mechanism
>   for query string authentication for buckets and objects. Signed URLs
>   provide a way to give time-limited read or write access to anyone in
>   possession of the URL, regardless of whether they have a Google
>   account. To learn how to create a Signed URL, read [Creating Signed
>   URLs with gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-gsutil) and [Creating Signed URLs with a Program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program).

Since you plan to do it from your code, the 2nd approach from the above quote is what you need - essentially boiling down to sending a particular POST request to a specially crafted URL.